# REACT - Express : fetching data doesn't work on reload when user connected

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, fetch

I've deploy my first app using React with Nodejs/Express/MongoDB but I'm running through a bug I couldn't find any solution, so I'm coming here to find some help.

This is the app : https://movie-app-marielyse.herokuapp.com/

As soon as the user connects, he can access the data, but if the page is reloaded, the fetch is not working anymore.

Here is the code where the fetch happens :

```
import './App.css';
import "./index.css"
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Register from './components/Register';
import Login from './components/Login'
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Auth from './pages/Auth';
import Movie from './pages/Movie'
import NotFound from './pages/Notfound';
import FavoritesMovies from './pages/Favorites';
import UserContextProvider from './contexts/UserContext';
import RequireAuth from './contexts/RequireAuth';

function App() {

  const defaultUser = {name:"Stranger", email: "stranger@gmail.com"}

  const [moviesList, setMoviesList] = useState([])
  const [initialML, setInitialML] = useState([])
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(defaultUser)
  // console.log(userInfo.name)
 
useEffect( () => {getMovies()}, [])

  function getMovies() {
    fetch('/movies')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const movies= data.movies
      setMoviesList(movies) 
      setInitialML(movies) 
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <UserContextProvider user={{userInfo, setUserInfo}}>
          <Router>
            <main>
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home moviesList={moviesList} setMoviesList={setMoviesList} initialMovieList={initialML}/>}/>
                <Route path="/auth/*" element={<Auth />} >
                    <Route path="login" element={<Login/>} />
                    <Route path="register" element={<Register/>} />
                    <Route path="logout" element={<Register/>} />
                    {/* <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />}/> */}
                </Route>
                <Route path="movies/:movieId" element={<Movie moviesList={moviesList} setMoviesList={setMoviesList}  />} />
                <Route path="favorites" element={
                      <RequireAuth> 
                        <FavoritesMovies />
                      </RequireAuth>} />
                <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />}/>
              </Routes>
            </main>
          </Router>
          </UserContextProvider> 
     

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: this happens only when user signup & login and do refresh while seeing list of movies- `movies` endpoint is pending. Can be checked in network tab of browser. Once you logout and login again - you see movies, but then after refresh no list of movies is displayed. Blindly, i would try to move `useEffect & fetch` inside `<Home />` component.

Also, sharing `Home` component can be useful for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home moviesList={moviesList} setMoviesList={setMoviesList} initialMovieList={initialML}/>}/>
```

On this line  or where ever there is `moviesList` and `initialML`  try doing:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home moviesList={moviesList && moviesList} setMoviesList={setMoviesList} initialMovieList={initialML && initialML}/>}/>
```

Your fetch request is async so it takes some time but the compenent is already rendered before that thats probably it looks data is not being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

In general your code can be modified like this, roughy:

- remove fetch /movies from `App` and place it inside `Home` - this would make sure useEffect/fetch triggers when `/` route is hit. And is good practice to keep things separated and well organized.

**App component**

```
function App() {

  const defaultUser = {name:"Stranger", email: "stranger@gmail.com"}
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(defaultUser)

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <UserContextProvider user={{userInfo, setUserInfo}}>
          <Router>
            <main>
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}/>
                <Route path="/auth/*" element={<Auth />} >
                    <Route path="login" element={<Login/>} />
                    <Route path="register" element={<Register/>} />
                    <Route path="logout" element={<Register/>} />
                    {/* <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />}/> */}
                </Route>
                <Route path="movies/:movieId" element={<Movie moviesList={moviesList} setMoviesList={setMoviesList}  />} />
                <Route path="favorites" element={
                      <RequireAuth> 
                        <FavoritesMovies />
                      </RequireAuth>} />
                <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />}/>
              </Routes>
            </main>
          </Router>
          </UserContextProvider> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home component**

```
function Home() {
  const [moviesList, setMoviesList] = useState([])
  const [initialML, setInitialML] = useState([])
 
  useEffect( () => {getMovies()}, []);

  function getMovies() {
    fetch('/movies')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const movies= data.movies
      setMoviesList(movies) 
      setInitialML(movies) 
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  return (....)
}
```

And i am not sure which version you are using but if it is not v6, more on React.Router could be checked- https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch and `exact` https://dev.to/danhjoo7/using-a-switch-component-in-react-router-d2k